# Support of If-Modified-Since HTTP header

Tags: google

On Google Webmaster Guidelines I see this:

"Make sure your web server supports the If-Modified-Since HTTP header. This feature allows your web server to tell Google whether your content has changed since we last crawled your site. Supporting this feature saves you bandwidth and overhead."

(at this link: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#1 )

I contacted Godaddy and they told me:

"I understand you would like to know if your server currently has the "If-Modified-Since HTTP header" installed.  I used an external tool to test this and found that it is not currently being utilized by your server.  Additionally I was unable to find a reliable source to get specific requirements on what this server needs to function.  In order to determine if your server supports this you will need to provide us the exact specifications required to run it."

How do I ensure the If-Modified-Since HTTP header is supported and that it is active?

Thanks

Comment: Please add information about your web server software as well as information about how your content is implemented (if it is static pages or generated by PHP, or...).

Comment: Is your site hosted by GoDaddy?  That's an alarmingly (but not surprisingly) clueless response, if so..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .htaccess file and match up the $_SERVER variables from within.

It is proven to work in GoDaddy shared hosting environments.

See this link:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html